# Assistance needed, Mac terminal requires input to be used

Tags: mac, terminal

Basically, my terminal opens up and it is just blank, the title of the window shows that it is python, and when I go to close it asks if I want to terminate `-zsh, python`. If I wish to use it I need to press a button, or wait some time. I am not sure how to fix this, and would like any help possible as I use the terminal frequently in programming.

I don't have enough 'reputation' to post images, though I would like to. I hope the description above is sufficient enough to understand, if anything is confusing or needs clarification please feel free to comment on it.

Comment: Sounds like your shell startup script is calling Python at some point.

Comment: @DanielB I checked my terminal preferences and in the shell tab, it is not running any command, I am not sure if this is what you mention.

Comment: @blamechickenman After your terminal emulator starts your shell program (e.g. zsh), your shell program runs its startup scripts. Read the documentation for your shell to see what startup scripts it looks for and runs in different situations, to see which files you need to check, like maybe `~/.zshenv`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.zprofile`, or `~/.zlogin`.

Comment: @Spiff Cheers, this helped a ton.